# Can you use equals assignment when removing delegate members in a disposing method?

Tags: c#, delegates, operators, variable-assignment, dispose

I have the following code in my class

```
public class Receiver : IReceiver
{

    public event EventHandler Received;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Received != null)
            {
                foreach (EventHandler delegateMember in Received.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    Received -= delegateMember;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works in that when I dispose my class any events that are hooked up to the Received event, will be removed individually.

I've been wondering if rather than being so verbose about it, if the following terse version will have the same effect

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Received = null;
        }
    }
```

Basically this comes down to how the operator overloads have been created by Microsoft when implementing the delegate overloads.  I know that all the documentation says to use the += to subscribe and -= to unsubscribe from an event.  I've also seen the document say that the event will be assigned to null when the last subscriber is removed.  What the documentation does not say is whether assigning the event to null, will have the effect of unsubscribing all the events?

I'd love to know if this is possible, and if there is any documentation that says that the possible terse code is correct behaviour.

Update:

I've been doing some more digging with the c# compiler and have found that the assignment to null only works within the class where the event is defined.  The += and -=  is always available from both inside and outside the class.  This leads me to be thinking that using the = null version is acceptable.  However, this is speculation, I still have not seen any documentation that states explicitly states this is supported functionality.

Comment: @DStanley The delegates would still be referencing those objects, yes, but the delegate itself would no longer be rooted, or accessible from a root, so it wouldn't be keeping those referenced objects alive.

Comment: I did check for quiet a while before posting the question.  Bascially the question is using = verses using -=.   In the MSDN the closest that I can find is at the bottom of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.90).aspx  it says that null will be assigned when the last instance of the event handler is unsubscribed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason not to just assign `null` to the delegate here.

You wouldn't be *able* to just assign `null` if you were outside of the class that defined the event.  To anyone using the class they should only be concerned with their own handlers, that they can add or remove.  They aren't able to access the handlers of others.

You need to remember that delegates are immutable.  Using `+=` on an event doesn't mutate the delegate to add a new method to that delegate, it creates a new delegate that, when invoked, calls both of the delegates that were added together.  Using `-=` creates a delegate that invokes all of the invocations of the first operand except for the second operand.  So calling `-=` over and over is continually creating more and more delegates that each invoke less and less stuff, until eventually you get to the point that the delegate isn't invoking anything anymore.  Just assigning `null` is equivalent to just creating a delegate that does nothing, and assigning that directly.

So when you call `-=` over and over the original delegate that was assigned to the event before you started still exists, as well as N intermediate delegates.  That said, none of the delegates are likely to be referenced by any rooted element, so they'll all be eligible for collection.  If you just assign `null` you still have the same orphaned delegate that was originally there, you just don't have any of those intermediate delegates anymore.

Comment: I understand everything that you have posted here, and I know that the code will compile both ways.  I suppose the key part of the question is... is that -= doing something else as well, but the = assignment isn't doing?  And if it is how can you be sure?   The only reference that comes close to this that I've found so far is at the bottom of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.90).aspx which explicitly says to use the -= operator.  It does say that you can test for null to see if there are any subscribers.  It does not say that you can use the = operator.

Comment: @ColinDawson The `-=` operator is not doing anything besides creating a new delegate that excludes the second operand from the invocation list and then assigning that new delegate to the first operand.  Creating a new delegate that does nothing (a.k.a. `null`) and assigning it directly is thus equivalent.  Of course, unless any of the event handlers reference the object defining the event (and will outlive this receiver), there's no reason to do *either*, as the entire receiver should soon cease to be rooted in the first place., and there's no reason to null it out.

Comment: I understand that, the question isn't can you write it in code, but is there any documentation that supports using = null?  I'd love to be able to simply using the terse code as it looks extremely clear, but I want to be sure that under the hood everything is working as intended - the same way as the verbose code from the example.  What I'm looking for is the citation that says it is an allowable construct.  I don't want to assume that it works.  What you are saying makes sense, I'd understand how you came to that understanding.

Comment: I disagree with the middle of the last paragraph -- `Dispose(true)` gets called for the express purpose of releasing resources when the main object is (or may  be) ineligible for collection.  By assigning `null`, you proactively unroot the multicast delegate.

Comment: @ColinDawson: You seem to have a misconception that events or delegates are special -- they aren't.  The backing field for the event has delegate type, as long as it points to a delegate object, the invocation list of that delegate holds references to objects and keeps them from being collected.  When the backing field is set to `null`, it won't keep the delegate object alive, or any of the downstream objects (although they may continue to be reachable from other parts of the rooted object graph)

Comment: @BenVoigt can you elaborate? for a start when you say middle of the last paragraph - was that before or after the update?  what exactly are you disagreeing with?   And more constructively, what would you assert and why?

Comment: @BenVoigt The expressed purpose of `Dispose` is to clean up unmanaged resources that the GC won't clean up.  Typically objects are disposed after they are no longer used, when they are just about to reach the end of their lifetime.  They're always going to still be rooted when being disposed, but they're frequently about to no longer be rooted.  While one could use `Dispose` to remove references to managed objects, allowing them to potentially be cleaned up before the "disposed" object, I would consider that a very atypical usage of disposal, and a red flag that something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @ColinDawson: I say that yes, `if (disposing) { Received = null; }` is good practice.  It does break the links from your object to the targets of the multicast delegate, that might otherwise keep those alive, and it's not useless, because people do call `Dispose` on objects (yours) that remain reachable.  Also, it prevents you from accidentally triggering events after disposal, and having them reach objects which are themselves no longer ready to handle events.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not a misconception, I'm deliberately trying not to assume how anything works.  To elaborate, my assumption is that the whole delegate thing is simply a list stored behind the scenes, items are added to it and removed from it with += and -=, setting it to null is like calling clear.  I'm getting ready to teach this, so rather than pass on assumed knowledge, I would love to have something more tangible that I can use to backup if I say that = null is acceptable.  Hence, not making the assumption or which what it is working.

Comment: @BenVoigt Continuing to use objects that have been disposed is already a *big* red flag that something is wrong.  There are situations where it can be worth doing anyway, but they should absolutely be the exceptional cases, not the norm.  One should assume that disposable objects are typically never used once disposed.  Although they shouldn't destroy the world if used anyway (throwing an ObjectDisposedException is usually the right option).

Comment: @ColinDawson: Setting it to `null` is not like calling clear, which leaves you with an empty list, it's like setting a field with list (reference) type to `null`.  There is not an empty list, there is no list.

Comment: @Servy: Events flow in the opposite direction of "usage" of the object.  Just because you no longer use a disposed object, does not mean that events cannot arise from previous actions taken.  Sure, the object should detach all of its handlers during `Dispose`, but if multiple threads are involved, blocking events which may be in the process of being handled gets complicated, fast.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was paraphrasing.    Allow me to start again.  What I'm trying to find out is if there is a document from Microsoft or someone else that backs up everything that has been said.  Up to this point, this "could" be taken as an undocumented feature, or even worse assumed knowledge.  I get that = null should work.  I've tested that is does work, but the MSDN and the ECMA both explicitly state that += and -= should be used to subscribe and unsubscribe.  There is not mention of  the = behaviour in the documentation.   I'm looking for the documentation.

Comment: @ColinDawson: You mean this quote from the language specification?  "**Within a class that declares an event member, the event behaves just like a field of a delegate type** (provided the event is not abstract and does not declare accessors). The field stores a reference to a delegate that represents the event handlers that have been added to the event. If no event handles are present, the field is null."

Comment: Perfect, that's from 1.6.7.4 of the CSharp language specification which installed with Visual studio.  I didn't know that document existed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: A *variable* of delegate type behaves as a mutable list *itself*, rather than as a reference to one; the usage of the variable dictates that having the delegate be `null` is semantically equivalent to having the list be empty.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That statement is no longer true.  For quite awhile, saying `eventName += someDelegate;` has been equivalent to something like `EventDelegateType temp,temp2; do { temp = eventName; temp2 = (EventDelegateType)(Delegate.Combine(temp, someDelegate)); } while(Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(eventName, temp2, temp) != temp);`

Comment: For those who want to see the document it's available here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029